# Finding the eigenvectors, eigenvalues, characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the characteristic polynomial, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and if possible, the invertible matrix P such that $P^{-1}$AP is diagonal for matrix A =

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -3 \\ 2 & 0 & 6 \\ 1 & -1 & 5 
\end{pmatrix}$$

My approach: since det( $\lambda I_{n} - A$) = 0,

det( $\lambda I_{n} - A$) = $\begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & -3 \\ 2 & 0 & 6 \\ 1 & -1 & 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda - 1 & -1 & 3 \\ -2 & \lambda  &-6 \\ -1 & 1 & \lambda - 5 \end{pmatrix} = 0$

$$ = -1 ( -2 \cdot \lambda-5 - (-6 ]\cdot -1 )) = 0$$

$$= -1 ( -2 \cdot \lambda + 4 )= 0$$

$$2 \cdot \lambda -4 = 0$$

$$2 \cdot \lambda = 4 $$

$$\lambda = 2$$

Plugging in the eigenvalue 2 back into det( $\lambda I_{n} - A$): $$\begin{pmatrix} 2- 1 & -1 & 3 \\ -2 & 2 & - 6 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 - 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 3 \\ -2 & -2 & -6 \\ -1 & 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Row operations: $\frac{-1}{2} R_{1} + R_{2} , R_{1} + R_{3}$

Then,  $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I can get to this far. The textbook solution says that:

$$x = \begin{pmatrix} s-3t \\ s \\ t \\ \end{pmatrix} , x_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}, x_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I don't get what the textbook did to find x, x1, and x2.

Comment: @Loobear23 I took the $a_{1,2}$th entry of the − matrix. I edited the matrix in question, it looks like I missed some entries.

Comment: The determinant should give you a cubic polynomial in lambda not a linear one as you've gotten

Comment: You've calculated the determinant incorrectly.

Comment: Error in determinant aside, It seems that this question isn’t so much about computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors as it is about the basics of solving a system of homogeneous linear equations, i.e., computing the null space of a matrix. Do you remember how to do that?